# Why don't terminal IDs prevent unauthorized entery?

Tags: physical, cissp

I'm studying for CISSP and had gotten this question wrong. I also found it and the correct answer online, but still don't understand the reasoning.

[Source](http://www.rulit.me/books/cissp-practice-read-358822-282.html)

> 2. Which of the following controls is not appropriate to prevent unauthorized people from entering a computer center?
>
> a. Double-locked doors
>
> b. Television monitors
>
> c. Terminal IDs
>
> d. Picture ID badges
>
> 2. c. Logical access controls verify the terminal identification (ID) number and not a part of physical security. Logical access controls
>    provide a technical means of controlling what information users can
>    utilize, the programs they can run, and the modifications they can
>    make. The other three choices deal with physical security, which is
>    the right kind of control to prevent unauthorized people from entering
>    a computer center.

First of all, what is the definition of "controls"?

Second, I thought b) would be the correct answer because TV monitors don't actually prevent anything by themselves.

By terminal IDs do they mean the username/password a person can login to a computer with? This certainly seems ambiguous because it could also refer to a serial number used for keeping track of physical assets, or some sort badge that shows the person is allowed in.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I believe the terminal ID refers to a username/password, and yes it is rather ambiguous.

I think the idea it is trying to convey is that log in credentials prevent user operational access to a computer system, but do not actually prevent access to the computer itself.

Its easy to argue that TV monitors do not prevent unauthorized people from entering a computer center, and possible to argue that a "Terminal ID" could be used to verify a person before allowing phsical access. The word "Terminal" though almost universally means at least a screen with a fully fledged keyboard, as opposed to a keypad next to a locked door - and this is the only reason I would say that B is the most correct answer.

I say most correct because to me your answer is also a degree of correct. As is ID badges really. It's a poorly worded question with even poorer options to choose from.

Comment: Thanks. So what exactly is the definition of control? Is it short for "security control" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_controls ?

Comment: From the wiki `Security controls are safeguards or countermeasures to avoid, detect, counteract, or minimize security risks to physical property, information, computer systems, or other assets`, yeah that seems like a very good fit.